# Kendo Ui Grid Edit Popup Window validation - ASP.net MVC validation Summery

Tags: validation, grid, popup, kendo-ui

To my understanding ASP.net MVC validation Summery does not work in Kendo ui grid popup windows. 
Is there a way I can achieve this, so that I can display validation errors on popup windows similarly I show them on other views.

Or can I invalidate ASP.net validator conditionally from kendo validator.
Please reply me if there is a better way
Thank you.